# Proof a vector only contains -1, 0 and 1 under condition $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nv_i^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|v_i|$

Tags: analysis

For a vector $v\in R^n$, if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nv_i^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|v_i|$, then can we say the elements in $v$, $v_i\in\{-1,0,1\}$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Take $v_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $v_3,\ldots,v_n = 0$. Then $|v_2|$ solves the equation

$$\frac{1}{4} + |v_2|^2 = \frac{1}{2} + |v_2|.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = x^2-x$.

[image]

Look for $a,b$ such that $f(a) = -f(b)$. Then $v=(a,b,0,...)$ will satisfy $\|v\|_2^2 = \|v\|_1$.